# How to flatten an HLists of HLists

Tags: scala, shapeless

So at runtime I get an Hlist of Hlists which looks like:

```
(2 :: HNil) :: (1001 :: HNil) :: (1001 :: HNil) :: HNil
```

Here the type of the resultant Hlist is :

`(Int :: HNil) :: (Long :: HNil) :: (Long :: HNil) :: HNil`

but this could have been any other type at runtime. For example, it could have been

`(Int :: HNil) :: (String :: HNil) :: HNil`

Is there a way to flatten this HList like so:

```
2 :: 1001 :: 1001 :: HNil
```

with the following type:

```
Int :: Long :: Long :: HNil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it applying functional operations to HList. Take a look to how Poly works. First, we declare the Poly for **(Int::HNil) and (Long::HNil)**:

```
  import shapeless._

  object myPoly extends Poly1 {
    implicit val tupleIntCase: Case.Aux[(Int :: HNil), Int] =
      at(position => position.head)
    implicit val tupleLongCase: Case.Aux[(Long :: HNil), Long] =
      at(position => position.head)
  }
```

and using the map function you can extract and flatten the HList:

```
((2 :: HNil) :: (1001L :: HNil) :: (1001 :: HNil) :: HNil).map(myPoly)
```

It gives the desired result:

```
2 :: 1001 :: 1001 :: HNil
```

Note that the resulting type here is:

```
Int :: Long :: Int :: HNil
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Emiliano! I figured how polymorphic functions works. But I am struggling trying to make it work for generic HLists. For example, if I have a method that returns `HList`, `def returnsHList: HList = (2 :: HNil) :: (1001L :: HNil) :: (1001L :: HNil) :: HNil` how do I make the following work? `returnsHList.map(myPoly)`. This complains about no implicits found for HList.

Comment: @iamsmkr Returning `HList` rather than a subtype `L <: HList` is pretty rough. If the method is yours then you can try to modify it so that it returns a subtype.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the identity Poly defined by shapeless for conciseness:

```scala
import shapeless._
import shapeless.poly.identity

val nestedHList = (2 :: HNil) :: (1001 :: HNil) :: (1001 :: HNil) :: HNil
nestedHList.flatMap(identity)
// 2 :: 1001 :: 1001 :: HNil
```